# Deleting all Empty Form Fields from DOM on submit with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, shopify

So I am working on a conditional Shopify form which I inherited from another dev. Basically, it is using JavaScript/Jquery to validate fields and ensure that all required fields are filled out before going onto the next step. With a little doctoring, I got the validation working as intended but am having one problem. The issue is, because of the way the form is being setup to render conditionally, there are inputs set to style="display:none;" with JavaScript that get submitted blank. This is confusing, so I set up the following function:

```
$("body").on("click", "submit_button", function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (var i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) {
      if(elements[i].value == "" ) {
        elements[i].remove()
      }
    }
})
```

This works fine and dandy, but there is always one input left that is submitted blank which is fine, but not ideal.

I have double checked to make sure that the element that is submitting blank is indeed an input element (it is). I also originally set the loop up so that the for statement is as follows and saw the same result:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
```

Any ideas on why I'm left with one blank field on submission? Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you `console.log()` the value of each field, what does the one show that remains with your loop?

Comment: The element is part of the document and has a tag Name of input? According to the W3 documentation the < elements.length syntax is correct. The fact that changing the syntax from < to <= does not resolve the problen, tells us the issue is not an off by one error. That means that the element in question is not part of your array of input elements. Are you sure it has an "input" tag? Are you sure it is part of the "document"?

Edit: OR that means something is preventing you from deleting the last element of the array or the null array itself is being submitted on post.

Answer (score 2):

You have jQuery. You should use it.

```
$("body").on("click", "submit_button", function(){
  $(":text").filter(function () { return !this.value }).remove();
});
```

Comment: This did it! I can now submit and get only filled out fields. Thanks, @Tomalak!

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on why I'm left with one blank field on submission? Thanks for the help!

You may have a form field in there that isn't an `input` - the three main types of form elements are `input`, `select` and `textarea`. In your selector, you are only looking for `input` fields, so my guess is that the blank is coming from either a `select` or `textarea` that's also in the form.

Alternatively, your code may be breaking because you are `.remove()`'ing elements from an array as you are iterating over it.  This causes the array to change length as you are looping through it, which may cause you to skip over elements as their indices change.

Assuming that you only care about input fields that are actually in the form being submitted, there are some interesting features of forms and form elements that you can take advantage of here without using any additional selectors (jQuery or otherwise) for a bit of a performance boost.

Every form element knows about the form it belongs to (`<Element>.form`) and every form knows about all of the form elements it contains.  In fact, `<Form>.length` returns the number of such form elements (inputs, selects and textareas, as well as fieldsets, etc.), and `<Form>[i]` will give you the form element in the `i`th position (if `i` is an integer - so an array lookup) or all elements that have the name `i` (if `i` is a string - like accessing properties in an object)

Secondly, you can prevent sending data by either removing an element completely or by simply clearing the `name` property from the field. If we create a loop over the form's elements we can avoid problems with changing array indices by setting blank elements to have a blank `name` attribute.  (If we really want to axe the element though, we could also iterate through the array starting at index `(length - 1)` and finishing on index `0` - that way the changing indices only affect elements we've already checked)

Which is a bit of a long way to say that you can do something like this:

```
// Step 1: get the form element. 
// In a jQuery event listener, the keyword `this` will be bound to the element the event was attached to, which in this case will be the submit button.

var form = this.form;  // Every form element knows about its form

// Iterate through the form elements and remove the 'name' field from the blank elements.
for(var i=0; i<form.length; i++){  // form.length is the number of form elements
  var element = form[i];           // We can access form elements using their index
  if(!element.value){
    element.name = '';             // A field with no name will not be submitted
  }
}
```